# ethernet not working - xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, ethernet, tcp-ip

Here is the result of ifconfig

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:2e:5f:86:46:c5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2e:5fff:fe86:46c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:135540 (135.5 KB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1131308 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1131308 (1.1 MB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:10:7a:24:7f:c4  
          inet addr:10.122.138.189  Bcast:10.122.143.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2210:7aff:fe24:7fc4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13596 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7080753 (7.0 MB)  TX bytes:2200503 (2.2 MB)
```

Here is the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried a bunch of solutions from ubuntuforums but not a single one worked.

***Please help me out***

Comment: We'll need more information to help you out. What's the version of Xubuntu that you're currently running? Is this a new install, and ethernet never worked, or did something happen after a successful install? When you mention "I tried a bunch of solutions," that's not particularly useful. What specifically have you tried to do unsuccessfully so far?

Comment: @richbl - 1. 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: @richbl 2. The laptop has not been used for almost a year and i don't know its status from before. 3. I tried installing a driver. I couldn't find the link right now. The other solution was to add the connection information in the interfaces file but i didn't know what to add.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: didn't know i was supposed to edit the connection. it is working fine now. thanks